# Add sap.ui.commons.CheckBox onto a sap.m.page

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, checkbox, sapui5

I'm new to SAPUI5 and want to make a page, with contains several CheckBoxes, based on SAPUI5. At this moment I have following code to create the CheckBoxes:

```
function chosevalues(){
        re_items = [];

        var items = [];
        var text = ["1070","1071","1072","1073","1074","1075","1076"];

        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            alert("in for with i= " + i);
            var box = new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
                                text : text[i],
                                tooltip : 'Value checkbox',
                                checked : false,
                                change : function() {
                                    if(oCB.getChecked()){
                                        alert(this.getText());
                                        re_items.push(this.getText());
                                    }else{
                                        alert('NO');
                                    }
                                }
                });
                items.push(box);
        }
        page4.addContent(items);
        app.to("page4");
    }
```

Now I place the array on the page-content, but the text and the boxes are very small. 
I tried with a sap.ui.table.Table and also with a sap.m.List. Nothing worked. 
It should be like this: [SAPUI5 Explored - CheckBox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.CheckBox/preview) 
But I found no way to include the mvc-view in my javascript code.

On the one hand I can programm with javascript to create the CheckBoxes like the example, and on the other hand I can try to include the mvc-view. 
The Problem is, that I have no idea for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in SAPUI5 there are 2 major libraries - sap.ui.commons (for desktop only) and sap.m (for both desktop and mobile).

You have to decide which library suits most to your needs and go for it.

What you were trying to achieve (large check boxes) is possible only when using sap.m library.

Here is a small examle code based on your function:

```
var text = ["1070","1071","1072","1073","1074","1075","1076"];
var oVBox = new sap.m.VBox();
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    oVBox.addItem(new sap.m.CheckBox({text:text[i]}));
}
```

And here is a demonstration: [LINK](http://jsbin.com/fivasiyuca/1/edit?html,output)